# if statement is not repeating the function

Tags: javascript

for some reason when my function runs, it works the first time, but then it never hits thee else statement when the function is run again,im having problems with a few of these if statements in my code, this is just a basic one. What am I doing wrong? using vanilla javascript

```
function checkOffTodoItem(event) {
  var node = event.target.parentNode;
  var parent = node.parentNode;
  var classNames = parent.className;
  if (classNames = "li01") {
    var newList = classNames.replace("li01", "li02");
    parent.className = newList; 
   } else {
    var newList = classNames.replace("li02", "li01");
    parent.className = newList; 
  }
};
```

Comment: use === instead of assignment

Comment: You probably want to compare `classNames` value. Use `===` instead of `=` as `===` is comparison operator and is used to compare two values. `=` is assignment operator and is used to assign value to variable.

Answer (score 5):

use '===' for comparison with classnames inside if.

```
function checkOffTodoItem(event) {
  var node = event.target.parentNode;
  var parent = node.parentNode;
  var classNames = parent.className;
  if (classNames === "li01") {
    var newList = classNames.replace("li01", "li02");
    parent.className = newList; 
   } else {
    var newList = classNames.replace("li02", "li01");
    parent.className = newList; 
  }
};
```

Comment: Now instead of running once it doesn't work when I put the triple equal

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, a value not `null`, not `false`, not `undefined`, not `""` (empty string), not `NaN` (Not a Number), and not equal to `0` is **always** true in an if statement condition.

Hence, `"my string"` is `true`, `['my', 'array', 'of', 'string']` is `true`, `{"my": "great object"}` is also `true`.

In your code:

```
classNames = "Li01"
```

… means:

```
put the value "Li01" in `classNames` variable.
```

So, now:

```
`classNames` is equal to "Li01"
```

=>

```
`classNames` is true in an if statement condition.
```

=>

```
if ( classNames = "Li01" ) // => ALWAYS true
```

CQFD

Comment: Don't forget `NaN` and `""`, the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning rather than doing a comparison
You Need "=="
e.g.

```
if (classNames == "li01") {
  }
```

Comment: I tried == and === and the only one that works is the single =

Comment: Is this javascript? try console.log(classNames);

Comment: on the line above the if statement, then opening your developer console (f12)

Comment: @AndrewWaller What do you mean "the only one that works?" Isn't the whole premise of the question that it *doesn't* work?

Comment: @JJJ it works with the single equals but only once, where as the double and triple don't work at all